# Prevent websocket flood loop

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm developing an application where I use [WebSockets](https://github.com/websockets/ws) and nodejs, the question is:

How can I protect myself from someone doing:

```
var sockets = []
while(true){
    sockets.push(new WebSocket("ws://nodejsserver:port");
}
```

Is ip ban the only possible solution?

Thanks!

Comment: [This example](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#websocket-single-connection-prevent-flooding) with `rate-limiter-flexible` package should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security question. Let me rephrase it.

> What prevents you from doing `while(true) {http.request('google.com');}`

This is so-called DOS attack (Denial Of Service) by flooding the server with connections.

There are many ways modern applications prevent it.

1. Browsers do not allow opening more than 5 (?) simultaneous connections to the same server.
2. Some cloud hosting providers (like CloudFlare, DigitalOcean, etc) have some smart defenses against DOS and DDOS.
3. etc

You'd better try it yourself and tell us how it went.